# Spotify web api, get follow playlist's tracks

Tags: spotify

I want to get the tracks of a playlist that I follow via de new Spotify Web API. The issue is that, if the playlist isn't created by me, I get a 404 Error.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For next time, please provide the exact URL that you're calling, along with query parameters or potential body parameters. It makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

My assumption of what's going wrong here is that you're providing your own username instead of the playlist's owner's username as part of the URL.

Endpoint documentation for [Get a Playlist's Tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlists-tracks/):

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks
```

The `user_id` here is the playlist's owner's user id, and the `playlist_id` is of course the id of the playlist, e.g. `6sUmrBvbrRDDbaYJmO9DaE`.

Comment: So much thanks @michaelt I was putting my user_id instead of owner id.